# iOS OTA configuration for in-House apps?

Tags: ios, app-config, ota

Currently we have one iOS app deployed through Apple Enterprise (in House). All works fine, however. After installation, each device needs to be 'hand-configured' by going to the Setting -> My App (and there a IP address needs to be set).

My question is: is it possible with **one and the same** build, to send per device its own settings.bundle (or something similar) which would eliminate the needs for hand configuring each device?

Thanks.